# JDK 14.0.1 installed and "No Java runtime present, requesting install"

Tags: java, java-web-start

I found similar issues but none addressing the issue recently.

In a fresh installed Java, for the record:

```
java -version
openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 14.0.1+7)
Eclipse OpenJ9 VM AdoptOpenJDK (build openj9-0.20.0, JRE 14 Mac OS X amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20200416_40 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
OpenJ9   - 05fa2d361
OMR      - d4365f371
JCL      - 5757187cae based on jdk-14.0.1+7)
```

I'm trying to execute a simple:

```
javaws
```

And getting a

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.
```

In the aforementioned similar problems, the people correlated this to the lack of `JAVA_HOME`, which is not the case here:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/Users/fbarbeiro/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java
```

I'm using a MacOS High Sierra version `10.13.3`which I cannot update due to external dependencies.

Any clue in what could have been causing the `No Java runtime present, requesting install. Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.`?

Thanks

Comment: The default `javaws` command on OSX is at `/usr/bin/javaws`, is that what's getting displayed by `which javaws` on your machine? `javaws` is not provided by sdkman, and it's not in the sdkman path. The default OSX `javaws` is basically a "stub" provided by Apple. They also do that with `java` before you install a proper runtime.

Comment: Maybe one of the other JDKs provided via `sdkman` will include `javaws`; I'm also using `AdoptOpenJDK`, and `javaws` isn't provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`javaws` is the command to start the Java Web Start launcher.

Java Web Start was deprecated in Java 9 and removed in Java 11. You can downgrade from 14 to 10, or look for alternatives. I found this with an Internet search: https://openwebstart.com/

Comment: It's also not available in SDKs @ version 8 provided by sdkman, so I'm not sure that's gonna help in this instance. Sounds like he'll need to install the JDK via some other means

Comment: Openwebstart saved the day, in case someone else is facing a similar issue and don't want the hassle to change all the setup.

Comment: Why would the `javaws` app ship with new Macs if it is deprecated, unless it had a deprecation message? Instead, clicking on the Apple-provided pop-up dialogue brings me to the "Flash End-of-Life" page.